# tcpdf image is not showing in pdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

This is my code everything works fine expect logo image is not coming in pdf. This is my code for PDF generate.

```
$pdfimg->Image(''.JURI::root().'templates/camassistant_left/images/myvc_status.png', 0, 2, 250, 30, "", "", "", true, 550,'', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$pdfimg->Image(''.JURI::root().'templates/camassistant_left/images/myvc_status.png', 0, 2, 250, 30, "", "", "", true, 550,'', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Should be

```
$pdf->Image('images/image_demo.jpg', 15, 140, 75, 113, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
```

> **Note:** Make sure **image Exist in the path** (`templates/camassistant_left/images/myvc_status.png`)

**Brief**

`$pdfimg->Image` should be `$pdf->Image`

[tcpdf Tutorial](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_009.phps)

Comment: still image not coming

Comment: check image is corect

Comment: I have change code  $pdf->Image('templates/camassistant_left/images/exclude.jpg', 15, 140, 75, 113, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);

Comment: check the path exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `Image()` like:

```
$imapePath = JURI::root().'templates/camassistant_left/images/myvc_status.png';
Image($imapePath , 0, 2, 250, 30, '', '', '', true, 550,'', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Example of `Image()` function is like below:

```
//Image($file, $x='', $y='', $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='', $align='', $resize=false, $dpi=300, $palign='', $ismask=false, $imgmask=false, $border=0, $fitbox=false, $hidden=false, $fitonpage=false)
```

Let me know if there is query from you regarding this.